# Drupal urls include absolute paths

Tags: domain-access, uri

I just updated drupal core on website and my drupal alias do not work unless the full path to a directory is included

Example:
http://michael.tsikerdekis.com/ (works)
http://michael.tsikerdekis.com/publications (doesn't work)
http://michael.tsikerdekis.com/home/tsikerde/public_html/publications (works)

Why would the second option stop working.

Comment: Possibly you nuked .htaccess and some custom rules along with it. If nothing else, including server config, has changed, that’s quite likely to be what went wrong

Comment: Yeap nuked the .htaccess by accident. thank you for your help.